# How to get WebWorker instance from inside?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I have created a web worker using, but I could not find a way to get the instance of Worker from inside the Worker function.

From inside the function, if I use 'this' or 'self' then I only can get 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope' object.

Please see the code snippet below to understand the problem:

```js
/******** below is main.html file *********/
var mywebworker1 = new Worker('mywebworker1.js');
    
// register event listener to receive data from worker
mywebworker1.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  // at this point, 'this' == 'Worker' instance
  
  // ... other code
});


/******** below is inside mywebworker1.js file *********/
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  // at this point, 'this' == 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope' object
  
  // PROBLEM: How to get 'Worker' instance in here ??
  
  // .. other code
}, false);
```

I have tried to pass the Worker instance in postMessage, such as:

```js
// send command to start counting
mywebworker1.postMessage({"action": "count", "from" : 7, "to": 22, "instance": mywebworker1});

// GOT ERROR message = Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': Worker object could not be cloned.
```

Thanks in advance for the help~

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I have a need to set/add 'some states' into the 'Worker' object, so caller and other functions can see the state.

For example: is it busy ? is it finished ? what is the current progress ?

Comment: So why can't that be done using standard messages and some sort of state object?

Comment: The above snippet is only an example, the actual code is quite broad and the Worker states will be shared among different function, so I feel need the add some flags directly to the Worker object itself instead of making some global variables and doing many postMessage(), do you have any way to get the Worker  object instance from inside the Worker itself ?